# Show image while printing the web page

Tags: css

I am using media print to control the print of my web page where I do not want to show image in the web page but when user wants to print then I want to show those images.
I have written following code but its not working
    
In external css:

```
@media print { 
  img {
     display: block; 
  }
}
```

Comment: In my html i have written a following code:<img style="display: none; width: 100%; height: 100%;" src="abc.jpg" /><br/>;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the inline style of the `img` is `display:none;` it won't be overwritten in the `@media print` without having an `!important` tag.

You can either remove the inline style of the `display:none` or make your print query:

```
@media print { 
  img {
     display: block !important; 
  }
}
```

Additionally, here is an example using the background color of a div showing which ways will get overwritten and which way won't. **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mn9gf2om/)**

Comment: I have added that but still It does not show an image

Comment: Are you using a separate style sheet to handle the printing?

Comment: @rahul how did you link it? Did you include the media params? 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href=your/file/path" type="text/css" media="print" />` The thing you want to pay attention to is the **media="print"** you may have it as **media="screen"** that's a common mistake.

Comment: I have added it but still I cant see an image when I am trying to print a page

Comment: If you have the `media="print"` on your print only stylesheet, you can remove the `@media print { }` query brackets, let me know how that works.

Comment: I have to override all properties with !important for img tag. Now it works thanks